# Error when updating 2 to 3: Bad Request Unable to verify your data submission

Tags: craft3, installation, updating

Followed all steps on [Upgrading from Craft 2](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/master/en/upgrade.md) I have my .env, db.php, general.php and index.php in place... can't find any reference of this issue.

This happens after "To complete the update, some changes must be made to your database." and clicking on "Finish Up"

Comment: Can you zip up your `craft/storage/logs` files and send to support@craftcms.com?

Comment: I was able to fix it replacing the content of config/license.key by the word temp

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it replacing the content of config/license.key by the word temp

Answer (score 1):

I got this error and checked my error log. I found a bunch of errors like this:

2019-01-18 09:03:30 [-][-][soundnpevuons07lqg8c911grb][error][yii\base\ErrorException:2] yii\base\ErrorException: fopen(/craft/web/cpresources/725d4d8/jquery-ui.min.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:485.

When researching I found that there might be some write issue errors with the sub folders of the /web/cpresources folder. I cleared out all the sub folders and then tried to log in again. Now it all works.